# Experience with Hybrid Apps

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to learn from other's experience regarding Hybrid Apps. I want to make hybrid and I know Ionic, React and Onsen UI are some of the platforms on which I could create that.

Currently, I am working as an Android Developer and I want to go in hybrid ship too. However there are some of my questions, if someone could help me on these, then please do.

1. Is there any performance issue with hybrid apps.
2. How much time it take to create a Hybrid app comparative to native
3. What are the features of the native apps which can not be used in Hybrid apps.

Comment: This is a bit vague. It really depends on what kind of app you're trying to build.

Comment: Well, You are right. But how would I go on this, I dont know html java script css and angular

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'll try to answer your question the the best of my knowledge:

1. Yes there are of course performance differences, native languages like Java (Android) or ObjC/Swift (iOS) are compiled languages, Javascript on the other side needs to be parsed and then interpreted by the js-engine of a webview (the browser embedded in a native project). But modern bundling tools like webpack do a pretty decent job optimizing/minifing/splitting your javascript code into small chunks so *in most cases* performance should not be an issue. Angular for example also comes with its own "compiler" `ngc` wich precompiles your html templates. React uses virtual-dom, which is also really performant. If you want to do some really heavy things (e.g. optical character recognition) you can always do this on the native side of you hybrid app.
2. Coming to the time effort: As you mentioned you have no experience in writing any code on the web platform but still the learning curve for javascript (or as you are coming from the java world you will love typescript) is usually described as steep. Also most of the currently popular hybrid frameworks come with a big palette of prebuilt components which are ready to use - so spinning up a first app should not be too hard. What you should do definitely is reading about the basic concepts of javascript (like how asynchronity is handled in javascript, callbacks, closures, variable scoping, ...), otherwise you will have a hard time solving problems in your code. There are of course things that will take more time: For example if you have a use-case where you need native functionality and there is no existing plugin or library to do so - more on that in the next point.
3. If you need native functionality cou can always create a plugin for that (speaking of cordova because thats the platform I know best). Up to now I personally was always able to solve everything that was not possible in javascript by creating a native-plugin for it. This can be quite time-consuming sometimes but there is a huge amount of already existing plugins which will solve most of your problems.

I hope some of my opinions will be of help for you.